# Need help to convert string to dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I am creating a lambda function in AWS to execute SSM Automation document.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.start_automation_execution.

```
response = client.start_automation_execution(
DocumentName='XYZ',
Parameters={...}
```

)

I have stored the DocumentName and Parameters values in dynamodb table as below.

`"parameters_name": { "S": "'ParameterName1': [Variable1] , 'ParameterName2': [Variable2] , 'ParameterName3': [variable3] , 'ParameterName4': [Variable4] " }, "document_name": { "S": "XYZ" }`

** The variable values are obtained from an event as strings.

The definition for Parameters is as below in the boto3 documentation:

`Parameters (dict) -- A key-value map of execution parameters, which match the declared parameters in the Automation  runbook. (string) -- (list) -- (string) --`

Is there a way to convert the string to dictionary to below format:

`{'ParameterName1': [Variable1] , 'ParameterName2': [Variable2] , 'ParameterName3' : [Variable3], 'ParameterName4' : [Variable4]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a built in function called `eval` for this:

```
# need to append and prepend curly braces to the string first
my_str = "{'ParameterName1': [Variable1], 'ParameterName2': [Variable2], 'ParameterName3': [Variable3], 'ParameterName4': [Variable4]}"
my_dict = eval(my_str)

print(str(my_dict))
```

You can also use the `ast` library, which claims to be safer than `eval`, but this is because it enforces stricter rules on the string's format.

```
import ast

my_str = "{'ParameterName1': [Variable1], 'ParameterName2': [Variable2], 'ParameterName3': [Variable3], 'ParameterName4': [Variable4]}"
my_dict = ast.literal_eval(my_str)

print(str(my_dict))
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, eval function worked fine for me. The ast.literal_eval failed with "errorMessage": "malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f7990883d68>",
  "errorType": "ValueError",

Comment: Great! Yeah, the library functions are made safer primarily by requiring your string to be in a more specific format for it to be parsed safely.